# Unable to read typings for "es6-shim" during npm install

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am following deborah kurata's angular2 getting started course on pluralsight and installed node.js and then ran the npm install (after installing cntlm as I am behind a corporate proxy firewall). However I am receiving the following error

> > product-management@1.0.0 postinstall c:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Angular2
>   > typings install
>
> typings ERR! message Unable to read typings for "es6-shim". You should
>   check the entry paths in "es6-shim.d.ts" are up to date typings ERR!
>   caused by Unable to connect to
>   "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/D
>   efinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/es6-
>   shim/es6-shim.d.ts" typings ERR! caused by connect ECONNREFUSED
>   103.245.222.133:443
>
> typings ERR! cwd c:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Angular2
>
> typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601 typings ERR! command
>   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"     "c:\Users\vivekba\
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Angular2\node_modules\typings\dist\ bin.js"
>   "install" typings ERR! node -v v5.10.1 typings ERR! typings -v 0.7.12
>
> typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: typings
>   ERR!   https://github.com/typings/typings/issues
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating
>   system or architecture: fseve nts@1.0.11 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\ node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" npm ERR!
>   node v5.10.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   product-management@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the product-management@1.0.0
>   postinstall script 'typings install'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the
>   latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this
>   is most likely a problem with the product-management package, npm ERR!
>   not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your
>   system: npm ERR!     typings install npm ERR! You can get information
>   on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   product-management npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get
>   their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls product-management npm ERR!
>   There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     c:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Angular2\npm

Comment: `caused by connect ECONNREFUSED`

Answer (score 11):

If you are behind a **proxy** you can try this (it worked for me).

Create a `.typingsrc` file and add the following line with your proxy info:

`proxy="http://proxyname:port"`

[Source of my answer](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/120)

Comment: tried it but still does not work or throws the same error. i have also tried to use cntlm but ends up with the same error.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  Typings was not using the NPM proxy setting, adding the .typingsrc file with the same settings as my .npmrc file made it detect and use the proxy correctly

Answer (score 5):

The error is caused due to a connectivity issue.

> Your **firewall** is definitely at the root of the cause.

**UPDATE**

Some people have solved this through setting a configuration -

```
npm config set proxy "http://company.com:8000"
```

Or

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Or

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

You can check out the [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2728) too.

**SECOND UPDATE**

> If you're using VS then you need to set the config from the VS developer console

1. [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx) the VS developer console
2. Set npm configurations

Answer (score 4):

I solved creating `.typingsrc` file in the same folder, with the following content:

```
proxy = http://username:password@ip:port
https-proxy = http://username:password@ip:port
```

The words "username", "password", "ip" and "port" should be replaced with the values of your proxy.

Answer (score 3):

I solved following the link in the Pere Page's answer. I've created a `.typingsrc` file with these lines:

`{
    "proxy" : "http://myproxy:port/",
    "rejectUnauthorized" : false
}`

Answer (score 0):

Create .typingscr file in your project folder parallel to package.json and put below line. Remember to put it in ini format not in json format.

```
rejectUnauthorized = false
```

I am using this behind corporate environment without any proxy setting and it worked for me, hope will work for you.