# typings install permission error

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I have been developing an angular2 typescript application with npm, typings. post npm install when i do "typings install" I see am bilow error.

I tried other solution provided for the typing in stackoverflow but no luck.

C:\quickstart>npm install

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall \quickstart
>   typings install

typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/selenium-webdriver/tags/2.44.0%2B20160317120654"
typings ERR! caused by unable to get local issuer certificate

typings ERR! cwd C:\quickstart
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
typings ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\quickstart\node_modules\typings\dist\bin.js" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v6.3.1
typings ERR! typings -v 1.4.0
typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   https://github.com/typings/typings/issues

Comment: have you tried to manually install the selenium-webdriver definitions?  `typings install dt~selenium-webdriver --global`?

Comment: it look like its unable to read the property from typeings site due certificate issue.  
typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/selenium-webdriver/tags/2.44.0%2B20160317120654" typings ERR! caused by unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered at

[npm install error unable to read typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762929/npm-install-error-unable-to-read-typings/39707899#39707899)

Try few options available there. the last one worked for me.